# which section of the data warehouse design used to analyse KPI?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

Hey guys i have just started studying about data warehousing in university can anyone tell me which section could be used to analyse and investigate kpi measure?

is it the ETL process that a person could learn about kpis?

thanks
help  would be  much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

performance indicator (KPI) are related to cube in analysis serivce (SSAS).Please go 
through the msdn link for further details

[KPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174538%28v=sql.90%29)

Comment: so the cube is used to analyse and investigate the KPI measure?

Comment: Yes . U basically add KPI to your cube to analyse business performance which is shown in cube data